# Refactor Code For HackerRink Solution (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, sorting

I'm trying to solve a very simple HackerRank test, I have some code that I believe is pretty clean and refactored...but it always times out on the last test-case. I downloaded the input for it, and it's an insanely large string of values, but other people pass just fine with even more complex code. I would like some help to find a cleaner way to represent my solution, if there is one.

This is the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation

A left rotation operation on an array of size  shifts each of the array's elements  unit to the left. For example, if left rotations are performed on array , then the array would become .

Given an array of  integers and a number, , perform  left rotations on the array. Then print the updated array as a single line of space-separated integers.

Input Format

The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of  (the number of integers) and  (the number of left rotations you must perform). 
The second line contains  space-separated integers describing the respective elements of the array's initial state.

Sample Input

5 4
1 2 3 4 5

Sample Output

5 1 2 3 4

Here is my solution:

```
import Foundation

func shift(_ a: [String], n: Int, d: Int) -> String {
    var s = a
    for _ in 0 ..< d {
        let v = s.remove(at: 0)
        s.insert(v, at: n-1)
    }
    return s.joined(separator: " ")
}

let values = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map { Int($0)! }
let line2 = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ")
print(shift(line2, n: values[0], d: values[1]))
```

Can anyone help me find a cleaner way to solve this? My solution always times out on one of the last two test-cases.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do a swap as you're already creating a copy of the array (var s) so just use that. I.e. take from the source and output into s, nice and simple example:

```
func shift(_ a: [String], n: Int, d: Int) -> String {
    var s = a
    for i in 0 ..< n {
        s[i] = a[(i + d)%n]
    }
    return s.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

Comment: Yes! This allowed every test-case to execute successfully! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of remove/insert-ing elements which should take O(n) depending on the data structure used, do swaps on the array instead.

```
func shift(_ a: [String], n: Int, d: Int) -> String {
    var s = a
    for i in 0 ..< d {
        var t = s[0]
        s[0] = a[(i - d)%n]
        a[(i - d)%n] = t
    }
    return s.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

I didn't run this so do make sure that the code is correct, but the idea is there.

Comment: So something like `swap(&s[0], &s[n-1])` ? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I still kept getting a time out, but Michael's answer above which is similar actually got me through. I appreciate everyone's help. Still get an up vote from me